# Does succinic acid provide any caloric value in humans?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, food-chemistry

Would the ingestion of pure succinic acid provide any caloric value in humans? I couldn’t find any nutritional information about it via Googling, but I read on Wikipedia that it’s converted into fumaric acid, which after Googling I found does have a caloric value of around 2.74 Kcal/g.

I don’t fully understand exactly how succinic acid is metabolised though, be it where it’s metabolised or the amount of it that can be metabolised, so I’m simply lost with the numbers.